# sql select dates for current and prev month

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Please help whith query. Have a table:

```
id | u_id | start_date |  end_date  |
-------------------------------------
01 |   7  | 2012-09-05 | 2012-09-23 |
02 |   4  | 2012-09-10 | 2012-09-15 |
03 |   4  | 2012-09-27 | 2012-10-05 |
04 |   5  | 2012-10-01 | 2012-10-09 |
05 |   4  | 2012-10-10 | 2012-10-15 |
06 |   7  | 2012-10-23 | 2012-11-05 |
07 |   5  | 2012-11-05 | 2012-11-12 |
08 |   4  | 2012-11-08 | 2012-11-10 |
```

I want to select all records where month=10 and max "start_date" from prev month and min "end_date" from next month.
Needed as a result

```
id | u_id | start_date |  end_date  |
-------------------------------------
03 |   4  | 2012-09-27 | 2012-10-05 |
04 |   5  | 2012-10-01 | 2012-10-09 |
05 |   4  | 2012-10-10 | 2012-10-15 |
06 |   7  | 2012-10-23 | 2012-11-05 |
```

I don't understand what i do wrong with this query

```
SELECT start_date, end_date
FROM _xata_owner 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT max(start_date) AS date FROM _xata_owner
   GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(start_date, "%m")
   ) b ON month(b.date)=09
WHERE month(start_date)=10
ORDER BY start_date
```

Thanks!

Comment: what's the end_date and start_date types you are using in mysql?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. You say you want the month in start_date to be "10", but one of the start_date fields in your "desired results" is "09". Also, you are joining every row in the result with the maximum start date where the month is 9. So every row will have a field called "date" with value "2012-09-27".

Comment: You said you want also the max END_DATE from the previous month. So, why did you put "2012-09-27 | 2012-10-05" on the desired results if the record with the max end date of the previous month is "2012-09-10 | 2012-09-15"?

Comment: it will be a calendar for current month. each day have multiple events with time period from start_date to end_date. So if event start in prev month(2012-09-27) and end in current(2012-10-05) me need output this 5 days in current moonth

Comment: Wait, so you just want the events that somewhat happen in the current month?

Comment: sorry I'm confused. max(start_date) from prev month

Comment: 2 Geoff_Montee. yes but if event start in prev month end end in current it must printed

Comment: But you are making assumptions. For example, an event that starts in august and ends in december still happens in october, but it doesn't fit the arbitrary criteria you mentioned.

Comment: I did not even think about that, you are greate thanks! But in my case week is max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want:

- Get records where the month in start_date is 10. For that:

  SELECT id, u_id, start_date, end_date
  FROM _xata_owner 
  WHERE month(start_date)=10
- Get the max "end_date" where the "start_date" is in the previous month:

  SELECT id, u_id, start_date, end_date
  FROM _xata_owner
  WHERE month(start_date) = 09 AND end_date =
          (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM _xata_owner WHERE month(start_date) = 09)
- Get the min "end_date" where the "end_date" is in the next month:

  SELECT id, u_id, start_date, end_date
  FROM _xata_owner
  WHERE month(end_date) = 11 AND end_date =
          (SELECT MIN(end_date) FROM _xata_owner WHERE month(end_date) = 11)

Put them all together:

```
(SELECT id, u_id, start_date, end_date
FROM _xata_owner 
WHERE month(start_date)=10)
UNION
(SELECT id, u_id, start_date, end_date
FROM _xata_owner
WHERE month(start_date) = 09 AND end_date =
        (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM _xata_owner WHERE month(start_date) = 09))
UNION
(SELECT id, u_id, start_date, end_date
FROM _xata_owner
WHERE month(end_date) = 11 AND end_date =
        (SELECT MIN(end_date) FROM _xata_owner WHERE month(end_date) = 11))
```

This sounds like what you want anyway. Your question is a little confusing.

Comment: BIG Thanks! did not want to do it through UNION trying to find another solution, but this is probably the only way. By the way second union in my case not need, in first select with start_date we alredy have end_date with month 11. I probably have a little bit confused)